# any explanation on the following regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I met the following the regex in ruby code, anyone could detail this to me?

```
[\w-]+\.(?:doc|txt)$
```

especially I think I am not clear about `[\w-]+\` and `?:`

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988

Comment: @Drenmi Different languages have different regex syntaxes. You need to mention which variant of regex you are using. This question is about Ruby **and** about regex. If you do not fix your edit, someone (including me) will fix it at some point.

Comment: @sawa: Now we both put it in, so we can be sure it's there. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is a sequence of one or more letter/number/underscore/hyphen, followed by the period, followed by either `doc` or `txt` at the end of a line.

- `[\w-]` is letter/number/underscore/hyphen.
- `\.` is an escaped period.
- `(?:`...`)` is a grouping (required to express options between `doc` and `txt`) that would not appear in the result as a captured substring.

It is likely written for searching a file name with the extension `doc` or `txt`, embedded within a multi-line string. Or, if the author of that regex is stupid (mistaking `$` for `\z`), then it might have been intended to simply match a file name with that extension.

Comment: @DamianoStoffie Sorry, my answer was incomplete. Now it's fixed.

Answer (score -1):

\w means any word character

minus in this context just means minus char

(?:doc|txt) means match doc or txt

so any word char or a minus repeated one or more times followed by a dot followed by either doc or txt and the pattern must be at the end of the line

the author should have escaped the minus for clarity imho

Answer (score -1):

There is an online regex tester available at https://regex101.com/
You can use it to analyse, verify or debug your regex strings. It already saved me tons of time.

Your regex detailed automatically with the help of that tool:

```
/[\w-]+\.(?:doc|txt)$/
        [\w-]+ match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
            - the literal character -
        \. matches the character . literally
        (?:doc|txt) Non-capturing group
            1st Alternative: doc
                doc matches the characters doc literally (case sensitive)
            2nd Alternative: txt
                txt matches the characters txt literally (case sensitive)
        $ assert position at end of the string
```

Comment: Would the down voter mind to explain his/her motivation?

Answer (score -1):

It means a file name which contains only word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore) and hyphens, and with an extension of either `.doc` or `.txt`.

In detail,

- `\w` matches a word character
- `[\w-]` matches either a word character or a hyphen
- `[\w-]+` matches one or more such characters
- `\.` matches a period
- `(?:)` forms a non-capture group
- `(?:doc|txt)` matches either a `doc` sequence, or a `txt` sequence
- In ruby, `$` matches the end of a line